# Hibernate Sessions Hanging?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, minecraft

I currently have a large game in which many connections are being written to our database. I will update player records after various actions are taken by the player (typically important events). To do this, I often utilize the following:

```
    /**
     * Commits an object to the database & saves it
     * @param entity - the entity to commit to the database
     */
    @Transactional
    public void updateActionList(List<DbEntity> dbEntityList) {
        
        try(Session session = Statics.getFactory().openSession()) {
            
            session.beginTransaction();
            
            int counter = 0;
            for(DbEntity entity : dbEntityList) {
                
                session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
                counter++;
                
                if(counter % 20 == 0) {
                    session.flush();
                    session.clear();
                }
            }
            
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Statics.NATIONS_LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

However, when the app attempts to shut down, we are met with a large stacktrace that *only* happens when our Hibernate is running:

https://pastebin.com/mdQBJ56H

out of that giant stacktrace, I noticed the following:

```
[17:14:34] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]: Current Thread: Hibernate Connection Pool Validation Thread
[17:14:34] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:      PID: 58 | Suspended: false | Native: false | State: TIMED_WAITING
[17:14:34] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:      Stack:
[17:14:34] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
[17:14:34] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
[17:14:34] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
[17:14:34] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
[17:14:34] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
[17:14:34] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
[17:14:34] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
[17:14:34] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[17:14:34] [Spigot Watchdog Thread/ERROR]:              java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My instincts tell me I'm doing something wrong with my Hibernate commits. Does anyone see anything glaringly wrong with my DB actions?

Comment: I have noticed few things, how the session is closed after work is done under transaction? what happens when you encountered an error, does the transaction rollback?

Comment: At the present moment, I don't have anything that manages transactional errors - there is no rollback.